# How to use variable inside regex when matching with multiple URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I am deleting the mutilple cached URL for specific user in my application.I store the user_id in all the URL,So when the specific user is logged out.Cache needs to be cleared for the specific user.I used the following,But it doesn't work.

```
cache_store.delete_matched('*id=#{current_user.id}*')
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Could you specify "doesn't work"? Do you get an exception or is the user simply not being deleted?

Comment: No i didn't get any exception and user's cached pages are still there.I inspected the regex and it gives *id=#{current_user.id}*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use double quotes for string interpolation:

```
cache_store.delete_matched("*id=#{current_user.id}*")
```

Comment: Funny, normally this stuff always happens seconds after the question was asked, but this one's almost an hour old :)

Comment: @padde If i want to match the exact number(current_user id) with multiple URL,how to match exact string with multiple URL?

Comment: I think i don't really get what you're asking for. Do you mean you want to build a regex that matches all strings that contain `'id=123'` (with `current_user.id = 123` as an example)?

Comment: A regex in ruby is delimited by slashes: `/regex here/`. The wildcard character (matches any character) is `.` which you can repeat zero or more times by appending an asterisk: `.*`. So you probably want something like this: `/.*id=#{current_user.id}.*/`

Comment: @padde I used this regex `cache_store.delete_matched("id=#{current_user.id}([^\d]|$)")` to match with multiple URL and delete which has id=94 and even if the id followed by anything.But It doesn't work in this case.help  me to solve this                                 `localhost:3000/foo/objects.text/html?id=94" localhost:3000/foo/objects.text/javascript?id=94&search=52" localhost:3000/foo/objects.text/javascript?id=94&search=521" localhost:3000/foo/objects/page/1.text/javascript?id=94" localhost:3000/foo?id=941                            localhost:3000/foo?id=943`

Comment: This is not a regex. It starts and ends with a slash, yours is in double quotes